# Store extracted value in csv file using jsr223 postprocessor in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jsr223

How can i store extracted value of a variable in a csv/text file using JSR223 post processor

Answer (score 2):

If this is something you **really** need to do in the JSR223 PostProcessor the minimal code would be:

```
new File('/path/to/your/file.csv') << vars.get('YOUR_VARIABLE_NAME_HERE') << System.getProperty('line.separator')
```

However if there will be a minimal concurrency you will run into the [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) when 2 or more threads (virtual users) will be writing into the same file resulting in data corruption

---

The approach which I would recommend is using:

1. Declare the variable you want to store via [Sample Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables) JMeter Property by adding the next line to *user.properties* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation):

   ```
   sample_variables=YOUR_VARIABLE_NAME_HERE
   ```
2. Once done you will be able to write the values using [Flexible File Writer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-the-jmeter-flexible-file-writer-plugin/) configured like:

   [image]

Answer (score 1):

You basically need to write the code to write into file.

Something like:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils;

attr1 = vars.get("attr1");
attr2 = vars.get("attr2"); 

f = new FileOutputStream(locationOfCSVOutputfile, true);

p = new PrintStream(f);


p.println(attr2+","+attr2);

p.close();
f.close();
```

Like wise get the values you need and write into the file by comma separated.

Beware that in multiple threads scenario, Many threads will be accessing same file. therefore the file output may not be what you expected. To overcome this I used a critical section controller.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

1/ Consider for example a node in your test plan with your request :

A regular expression extractor and a JR223 post processor component as child of your request.

2/ If you extract for example a multiple variable named "blabla" positioning the match number to "-1"

3/ Here's the piece of Groovy code that you can use in your post processor component to write your variable in a file :

```
import org.apache.jmeter.*;

File outputFile = new File("MY_FILE.csv")

int max = Integer.parseInt(vars.get("blabla_matchNr"));

for (i=1;i<max;i++)  {

    def word = vars.get("blabla_"+i);
    outputFile << word  << "\r\n"

}
```

Comment: javax.script.ScriptException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "ALJDN4BcpQE="

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "ALJDN4BcpQE="
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_241]
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_241]
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_241]
 at java_lang_Integer$parseInt.call(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]

Comment: I have added folloeing code in jsr223 post processor     import org.apache.jmeter.*;

File outputFile = new File("${pathToFile}")

int max = Integer.parseInt(vars.get("VisitId"));

for (i=1;i<max;i++)  {

    def word = vars.get("VisitId"+i);
    outputFile << word  << "\r\n"

}